# Cockroach connection best practice?

Tags: c#, npgsql, cockroachdb

I am using npgsql to connect to a CockroachDb cluster, in code with each command I want to execute I create a new connection and open it! I wonder if creating a private field variable holding the connection and opening it then closing it is much better than my current approach?

```
static async Task Task1()
{
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        new NpgsqlCommand("SQL Query here", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}

static async Task Task2()
{
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        new NpgsqlCommand("SQL Query here", conn).ExecuteNonQuery();

        conn.Close();
    }
}and so on ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really: although possible, it's a bit of an anti pattern.

[`NpgsqlConnection`](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html) inherits from [`DbConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbconnection). And `DbConnection` is a general Microsoft abstract class that represents a database connection, which is `IDisposable`.

So when putting the `conn` in a `using` block, you implicitly call `Dispose` as soon as it goes out of scope. *This will close the connection and clean up other stuff*. You don't have to separately call `Close`.

What you *could* do, is make a general wrapper like

```cs
public static async Task NonQueryCommand(string command)
{
    using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(command, conn) // Also IDisposable
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    } 
}
```

But you could lose all flexibility that way (the repository pattern can be bad if not used correctly).

Also check [the official resources](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/build-a-csharp-app-with-cockroachdb.html)